# Address open Layer in QGIS project by processing script, convert Python console into a processing script

Tags: qgis-processing, vector-layer, qgis-python-console

I created this code in the Python console, a new point layer is created with some attributes and set into edit and AddFeature mode. I would like to bring it in QGIS algorithms. I have tried a few things but I just don't have the expertise.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
#creat new layer
v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("point", "Windenergy", "memory")
# set CRS
v_layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(25832))

# Add new fields to tabel 
pr=v_layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("anl_typ",QVariant.String),QgsField("producer",QVariant.String),QgsField("power",QVariant.Double),QgsField("rdiameter",QVariant.Double),QgsField("hubheight",QVariant.Double),QgsField("total",QVariant.Double)])
v_layer.updateFields()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])

# aktiv editor and add feature
iface.setActiveLayer(v_layer)
qgis.utils.iface.actionToggleEditing().trigger()
qgis.utils.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'bring it into a processing script', is this not your script? Or do you want to add processing tools to this script?

Comment: i can imagine that i express myself incomprehensibly and the right choice of words is missing. sorry. Lets try it again.
So it works in the python console. But when I open the code in the processing script ediot or when I try to paste the code into the existing qgis script template it does not work. I don't know exactly what commands I need to import and what methods I need under QgsProcessingAlgorithm to run this code. If I need the initAlgorithm, because i dont have to define inputs or outputs? Or how I address the new layer then to get into edit mode.

Comment: when i run it i get this error: 'QgsVectorLayer' is not defined